# Ionic 4 center ion grid within ion-content

Tags: flexbox, ionic4

I simply have an ion-content within that an ion-grid within that an h1.

```
<ion-content no-padding no-bounce>
    <ion-grid no-padding>
        <h1>ion-grid</h1>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

I have my ion-content set to 100vh, and the ion grid set to 80%; height. How do I vertically center the ion grid within the ion-content? And vertically center the h1 within the ion grid?

I tried setting the ion-content to display flex (which I'm sure it already is) and also align-content center. Same with the ion-grid.

Here is my CSS:

```
ion-content {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    align-content: center;

    ion-grid {
        display: flex;
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
        align-content: center;
    }
}
```

Heres the result (the ion-grid is stuck to the top of ion-content rather than vertically centered so align-content: center does not work. Same with ion grid and the h1):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With the below 3 lines we can add centered text.

```
<ion-content padding>   
  <ion-grid style="height: 100%">
    <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center style="height: 100%">
      <h1>ion-grid</h1> 
    </ion-row> 
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

[Here is the link for sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sv2c8k)

Answer (score 0):

```
Where is your row and column tags.  Like this!

<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      ion-col
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      ion-col
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      ion-col
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      ion-col
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="6">
      ion-col [size="6"]
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      ion-col
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      ion-col
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

I personnaly use this CSS code to center everything, put that on your `app.scss` file and call it everytime you want to center vertically and horizontally a component inside a ion-col :

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

So your solution is down here :

```html
<ion-content no-padding no-bounce>
    <ion-grid no-padding>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="flex">
          <h1>ion-grid</h1>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```